# Trying to make assistant but facing speed problem

Tags: python, performance, speech-recognition

My program is working perfectly fine but I am having speed problems. It takes too long to respond and give results. After 2,3 runs it takes more time than before. Also additionally it takes lots of time to start. What are the ways to speed up of program? I am new in this field.

```
# Imported speech recognition as sr, pyttsx3, pywhatkit, datetime, pyjokes, os
listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()


def talk(text):
        engine.say(text)
        engine.runAndWait()


talk('Hello what can i do for you')


def take_command():
        try:
            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                print("Listening...")
                voice = listener.listen(source)
                command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
                command = command.lower()
                if "jarvis" in command:
                    command = command.replace('jarvis', '')
                    return command
                else:
                    talk("I cannot continue until you say jarvis")
                    take_command()
        except:
            pass


def run_jarvis():
        command = take_command()
        if not command:
            take_command()
        else:
            print(command)
            if "play" in command:
                song = command.replace("play", "")
                talk("playing" + song)
                pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
            elif 'time' in command:
                time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
                print(time)
                talk(time)
            elif 'joke' in command:
                joke = pyjokes.get_joke()
                print(joke)
                talk(joke)
            elif 'downloads' in command:
                path = "C:/Users\Mayur\Downloads"
                path = os.path.realpath(path)
                os.startfile(path)
            elif "whatsapp" in command:
                msg = command.replace("whatsapp", "")
                pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly("+91xxxxxxxxxx", msg)
                print("Successfully Sent!")
                talk("successfully sent")
            elif 'who is' or 'what is' or 'where is' or 'when is' or 'information' or 'which is' or "how is" in command:
                result = pywhatkit.info(command, 3, True)
                talk(result)
                print(result)
            else:
                talk('Sorry sir can you repeat again')


while True:
        run_jarvis()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly working fine for me and I didn't see any code that will make your program slow, and `listener.recognize_google(voice)` should connect to the internet to return result. So there may be your internet connection problem. And slow to start is fine because you have imported many different library to your program. Thus, that is making slow to start. Additionally it has to installize `recognizer` and `engine` that can also slow down the speed. Overall your program speed depends upon your computer speed and internet connection.

Comment: But after some continuous runs it becomes very slow. It feels like the computer is hanged

Comment: Your computer specifications? That is because your computer not working properly. Or other different programs are running with this program simultaneously. I can't tell you exactly this is your problem but i haven't found any specific code in your program that will make you program eventually slow.

Comment: Intel Core i5-1135G7 Processor.
8GB DDR4 2666 RAM